# O que significa test_size = 20?

Tags: python

Tenho a seguinte linha de código:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 20, random_state = 0)
```

O que significa test_size = 20?

Comment: qual biblioteca esta usando?

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento está certo, eu cometi uma falha e me esqueci de indicar a biblioteca. Sim, é Sklearn.model_selection - train_test_split. Obrigado por todas as respostas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que esta API se trate do https://scikit-learn.org/

Sendo assim esta usando a função https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

A descrição cita:

> `test_size`: `float`, `int` or `None`, `optional` (`default=None`)
>
> If float, should be between 0.0 and 1.0 and represent the proportion of the dataset to include in the test split. If int, represents the absolute number of test samples. If None, the value is set to the complement of the train size. If train_size is also None, it will be set to 0.25.

Tradução:

Se for `float`, deve estar entre 0.0 e 1.0 e representar a proporção do conjunto de dados (`dataset`) a ser incluído na divisão de teste (provavelmente seria como porcentagem).

Se for `int`, representa o número absoluto de amostras de teste (ou numero exato e não em porcentagem).

Se `None`, o valor é definido como o complemento do tamanho do `train_size`.

Se `train_size` também for `None`, `test_size` será definido como `0.25` (segue a regra do `float`, proporcional).

Comment: Por que o downvote? Falei alguma coisa errada ou traduzi errado o que esta na PROPRIA documentação?

Comment: Não vi nada de que justificasse um negativo.

Answer (score 1):

Da maneira como está definido, o valor 20 e o valor 0 representam valores padrões, ou seja, caso a função `train_test_split` seja chamada sem valores para os atributos `test_size, random_state` então esses valores serão atribuídos respectivamente.